# MySQL select last row of each one user from a list of users in a table

Tags: mysql, moodle

Im trying to select from a Moodle table the last row of each user in a list.
my query is

```
SELECT *
FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log
WHERE eventname='\\core\\event\\user_enrolment_created'
AND courseid=34
AND relateduserid IN(120,128)
GROUP BY relateduserid;`
```

and the table that i use is :

MariaDB [****_*****]> describe mdl_logstore_standard_log;

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | bigint(10)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| eventname         | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| component         | varchar(100) | NO   |     |         |                |
| action            | varchar(100) | NO   |     |         |                |
| target            | varchar(100) | NO   |     |         |                |
| objecttable       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| objectid          | bigint(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| crud              | varchar(1)   | NO   |     |         |                |
| edulevel          | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contextid         | bigint(10)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| contextlevel      | bigint(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contextinstanceid | bigint(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userid            | bigint(10)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| courseid          | bigint(10)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| relateduserid     | bigint(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| anonymous         | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| other             | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timecreated       | bigint(10)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| origin            | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip                | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| realuserid        | bigint(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My Problem with this query is that it give me the first row for every userid in list, and i want the last. i tried order by id desc but nothing changed.

Comment: how do you define **last row** ?

Comment: last inserted, last auto increment  id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
L.*
FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log L
INNER JOIN 
(

 SELECT 
  relateduserid,
  MAX(id) AS max_id
 FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log
 WHERE eventname='\\core\\event\\user_enrolment_created'
 AND courseid=34
 AND relateduserid IN(120,128)
 GROUP BY relateduserid
)AS t 
ON L.id = t.max_id
```

First getting the maximum auto increment id for those `relateduserids` then making an inner join between `mdl_logstore_standard_log` and `t` table would return your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but i didnt test it

```
select * from mdl_logstore_standard_log where eventname='\\core\\event\\user_enrolment_created' and courseid=34 and relateduserid IN(120,128)  GROUP BY relateduserid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: you can use with groupby also

Comment: no, this query, limit all the results to 1. i want 1 result from every user in list.

Comment: Keep in mind that tables in relational databases are just sets of rows. And sets in mathematics are unordered collections. There is no first or last row; no previous row or next row.
You'll have to sort your set of unordered rows by some field first, and then you are free the iterate through the resultset in the order you defined.